# Number of allowed user to connect with print server 2k3

Tags: print-server

Is there a limitation or number of allowed domain users connected to the print server.

Print server is on Windows Server 2k3.

We presently have a printer server installed in Windows XP and other users are just connecting to the specific workstation where the print server is reside. the problem is that Windows XP has a 10 connection limit only, so the User 11 cannot connect to the printer.

So if i make a printer server reside in server 2k3, is there also a user limitation when printing at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

No, the clients limit for Shared Folders and Printers on any Windows Server is unlimited by default.

But it is also "unlimited" if you use a Print Server, that is a much easier and cheaper long and short term solution than buying and setting up a Windows 2003 Server just because of a printer.

Also, there are some tricks online you can try to increase the number of connections on your Windows XP machine to up to 50 users.